# Git subtree. One common folder in two repositories

Tags: git, git-subtree, multiple-repositories

I have two projects, *ProjectA* and *ProjectB*. Each of them has its git repo. These projects have many of the same files. These files are in the folders named "*common*" both in *ProjectA* and *ProjectB*. Here is the files example:

*ProjectA*:

```
...
cat-folder
dog-folder

common
    commonFile1
    commonFile2

fish-file.php
squirrel-file.txt
...
```

*ProjectB*:

```
...
potato-folder
apple-folder

common
    commonFile1
    commonFile2

tomato-file.xml
pineapple-file.csv
...
```

I work on both projects. I may make changes on the common files working on *ProjectA* or *ProjectB*. I would like the changes of common files made in *ProjectA* also to appear in common files in *ProjectB* (and vice versa). 
So, I would like the "*common*" folder in both projects to be always up-to-date and to contain the same files.

For this I use **git subtree**. I have created the third repo "*common-repo*", put there all files of "*common*" folder, then deleted "*common*" folders from both projects. Then in each project I make this:

```
$ cd /path/to/ProjectA      # or ProjectB
$ git remote add common-repo https://my_user@bitbucket.org/url/of/common-repo
$ git fetch common-repo
$ git subtree add --prefix=common/ common-repo master --squash    # this command adds the "common" folder with my common files to the current project
```

Then, if I make changes in the *common-repo* and push them, I can easely pull them into *ProjectA* or *ProjectB*:

```
$ cd /path/to/ProjectA      # or ProjectB
$ git pull -X subtree=common common-repo master      # this pulls changes from common-repo
```

But the problem appears when I change files in the "*common*" folder working in *ProjectA* (or *ProjectB*) and try to push it to the *common-repo*.

```
$ cd /path/to/ProjectA      # or ProjectB
$ git subtree push --prefix=common common-repo master     # !!!!
```

The last command pushes all the files of the *ProjectA* to *common-repo*, including its non-common files!

How can I push to *common-repo* only files of "*common*" folder? 
Or maybe I do something absolutely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
git pull -X subtree
```

Try using the `subtree pull` command. Supposedly it is made to work along the `subtree push` and other `subtree` subcommands:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=common common-repo master
```

Comment: The command "git subtree pull --prefix=common common-repo master" works too. But after it "subtree push" is still pushing the whole project, instead of the only "common" folder.

Comment: Try doing first a `subtree split` to see what is being created, it may help troubleshoot if anything is amiss. `subtree push` is just a shorthand of a `split` followed by a `push` of the split branch.